# how to get data from database throught model using codeigniter with for each loop

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

http error occured while calling data from model using function

model

```
    public function getProductCombo() {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('products', array('type' => 'combo'));
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

controller

```
function sets() {
    $this->sma->checkPermissions();
    $this->load->helper('security');

    $this->data['error'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() :                         
                                                  $this->session->flashdata('error'));

    // problem in this line also
    $this->data['showcombo'] = $this->load->sales_model->getComboProduct();


    $bc = array(array('link' => base_url(),
                      'page' => lang('home')),
                array('link' => site_url('sales'),
                      'page' => lang('products')),
                array('link' =>   '#', 'page' => "sets")
          );
    $meta = array('page_title' => "Add Sets", 'bc' => $bc);
    $this->page_construct('sales/sets', $meta, $this->data);

}
```

Comment: What error are you exactly getting in that foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, No need to include the curly braces for `$q->result`

```
foreach ($q->result as $row)
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

No need to use validation_errors in your `php` file.You can directly load your `form` page.Use `validation_errors()` in view page.

In your Controller, do this

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('myform');
}
```

Then in your `formpage` you can `echo`

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line to 
`$this->data['showcombo'] = $this->load->sales_model->getComboProduct();`

this

`$this->data['showcombo'] = $this->load->sales_model->getProductCombo();`

Because your

model name is

```
 public function getProductCombo()
{

}
```

Comment: did you check the answer??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you load model in controller. And then called function, which you have defined in model..

```
          $this->load->model('sales_model','sales'); // sales is alias name of model name
          $this->data['showcombo'] = $this->sales->getComboProduct();
```